# Gray Scott Model

Tags: python, numpy, pde

I am trying to show the gray scott model of diffusion.  I keep getting a bunch of runtime warning errors even though I feel like my code is really close to correct.  Is there something wrong with my discretization?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#parameters
N=128
F=.042
k=.062
Du=(2**-5)*(N**2/6.25)
Dv=(1**-5)*(N**2/6.25)
tend=1000                             
dt=tend/N
t=0

#start arrays
U=np.ones((N,N))
V=np.zeros((N,N))

#Initial Value Boxes (20x20 in middle)
low=int(((N/2)-10))
high=int(((N/2)+10))+1
U[low:high,low:high]=.5
V[low:high,low:high]=.25

#Random Noise
U+=.01*np.random.random((N,N))
V+=.01*np.random.random((N,N))

#Laplace
def Laplace(f):
    return np.roll(f,1)+np.roll(f,-1)+np.roll(f,1,axis=False)+np.roll(f,-1,axis=False)-4*f

#Solve
pstep=100
for t in range(tend):
    U+=((Du*Laplace(U))-(U*V*V)+(F*(1-U)))
    V+=((Dv*Laplace(V))+(U*V*V)-(V*(F+k)))
    if t%pstep ==0:
        print(t//pstep)
        plt.imshow(U, interpolation='bicubic',cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

Comment: One issue, is that you should calculate `dU` and `dV` separately, and then do `U+=dU` and `V+=dV` otherwise you are using an updated U to calculate V. But that doesn't completely solve the numerical instability. I think that you may be calculating Du and Dv wrong? The values seem pretty high

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it to work by changing a few things in the calculation, but mostly altering the numeric stability by massively decreasing the diffusion coefficients, and decreasing the timestep. The net result of this, is that the whole simulation changes less between each step, so the value of the change is much smaller.

The errors you were getting were due to overflow of the floats in the calculation of `dU` and `dV`, by slowing the whole thing down (more timesteps) you don't need such massive numbers in `dU` and `dV`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# parameters
N = 128
F = .042
k = .062
# Du=(2**-5)*(N**2/6.25) # These were way too high for the 
# numeric stability given the timestep
Du = 0.1
# Dv=(1**-5)*(N**2/6.25)
Dv = 0.5
tend = 1000
dt = tend / N
t = 0
dt = 0.1  # Timestep - 
# the smaller you go here, the faster you can let the diffusion coefficients be

# start arrays
U = np.ones((N, N))
V = np.zeros((N, N))

# Initial Value Boxes (20x20 in middle)
low = int(((N / 2) - 10))
high = int(((N / 2) + 10)) + 1
U[low:high, low:high] = .5
V[low:high, low:high] = .25

# Random Noise
U += .01 * np.random.random((N, N))
V += .01 * np.random.random((N, N))


# Laplace
def Laplace(f):
    return np.roll(f, 1) + np.roll(f, -1) + np.roll(f, 1, axis=False) + np.roll(f,-1,                                                                              axis=False) - 4 * f


# Solve
pstep = 100
for t in range(tend):
    dU = ((Du * Laplace(U)) - (U * V * V) + (F * (1 - U))) * dt
    dV = ((Dv * Laplace(V)) + (U * V * V) - (V * (F + k))) * dt
    U += dU
    V += dV
    if t % pstep == 0:
        print(t // pstep)
        plt.imshow(U, interpolation='bicubic', cmap=plt.cm.jet, vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

Of course the changes I made alter the physics a bit, and you will need to alter your `t` and `pstep` so those values make sense. And also check how you were calculating `Du` and `Dv`. If those values are actually supposed to be ~8000, then you need a much much smaller timestep.

For anyone else's reference, the Gray Scott model is explained [here](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/projects/amorphous/GrayScott/)